# Math formula mixed with wrapfigure

Tags: wrapfigure

I use a wrapfigure as below:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{image.png} 
\end{center}
\caption{\small \sl My Diagram. \label{fig:image}}  
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Somewhere in my report i have a formula which passes right below the figure. (i.e between caption and figure). How can i prevent this?

Comment: It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  That way those trying to help can focus on solution as opposed to setting up the problem test case. Personally, I have often solved my own problems in the process of reducing the amount of code actually required to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The `wrapfigure` environment sometimes gets the height wrong. You can use an optional argument to manually specify the number of lines that the figure occupies. I would try

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[n]{R}{0.5\textwidth}
```

and adjust the parameter `n` until the problem goes away.

Comment: I believe that each line of 'math' still counts as a line even though they are much larger than the standard line, just in case you are wondering. IMHO it is a weakness in the wrapfig package.